# Under what circumstances can WPA be cracked?

Tags: wpa2, wpa-enterprise

can someone please tell me under what circumstances can WPA be cracked? i'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is susceptible to KRACK Attack. KRACK is attack is Key reinstallation attack. WPA2 also susceptible 2 KRACK attack.  WPA based on LEAP or TKIP and it use single passphrase for authentication. It is possible to brute-force very easily. Because passphrase is static.